# Issue while using Spring IO Platform

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-io

I have created a Spring MVC Project with Maven. I am new to Spring framework. With reference to [the following tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-getting-the-required-dependencies/), I am trying to analyze the Spring Data JPA repositories. I have enabled the Spring IO platform in my pom.xml with the following configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

After that I have added the other required dependencies without mentioning the version as follows:

```
<!-- Database (H2) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- DataSource (HikariCP) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Data JPA -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The tutorial says that Spring IO platform will take care of the versions. But When I try to do this I'm getting an error in my pom.xml saying that

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.h2database:h2:jar is missing.

Any suggestions that how can I use and enable Spring IO?

Comment: Is the bom dependency in de `dependencyManagement` section as explained in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-using-spring-io-platform-maven). For the managed version check [this](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following POM will work:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Database (H2) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DataSource (HikariCP) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

The important part is to put Spring IO dependency inside the `dependencyManagement` section of the POM. This is because it has the scope [`import`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

Comment: Thank you for your support. I got another issue which I posted in the following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807950/issue-with-spring-data-jpa-beanentitymanagerfactory Any suggestions please